# wp-config.php moved above root results in no plugin updates

Tags: security, wp-config

I copied original **wp-config.php** and saved it **above** the **root**.
In the root map there is now a wp-config.php with this settings:

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
require_once('/home/debxxx/security/domain.com/wp-config.php');
```

This works fine. Everything of the site works.
I only get an error message when a plugin update is started.

> Warning: unlink(/home/debxxx/security/domain/wp-content/uploads/updraftplus.1.12.25-YS3ytg.tmp): No such file or directory in /home/deb9xxx/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 505

In this example an error occurred:

> while updating UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.

- /home/debxxx/security/domain.com/wp-config.php >> position above site
- /home/debxxx/public_html/wp-config.php >> root map of site

How can I solve this so all updatings are still runs without errors and without to move “wp-config.php” to root map back?

ABSPATH = correct mapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the constants `WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME` and `WP_CONTENT_DIR` ? If not, that's likely to be your problem.

Comment: That could shure be the solution If I know how to fill both defines.

Comment: And in which of the wp-config.php files I have to do this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this previously! The one in the position above the root as I assume that's the active one!